# Logic to display table rows

Tags: email, email-template, table

I am display table rows in my email template...

```
<tr>
    <td>{!relatedTo.opportunity__r.name}</td>
    <td>{!relatedTo.opportunity__r.stageName}</td>
</tr>
```

However it is possible for opportunity__r to be null. I only want to add a row if the my custom object is pointing to a valid opportunity.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the block in an outputPanel and use rendered attribute and have a logic to render only if the value is not equal.Please note this you can have only if your email Template is a Visualforce template .

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered={!IF(relatedTo.opportunity__r.stageName!=null)}
<td>{!relatedTo.opportunity__r.stageName}</td>
</apex:OutputPanel>
```

Comment: this almost I workds. I had to do:  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(relatedTo.opportunity__r !=null, true, false)}">  I was interested in the Opportunity reference was null or set.

Comment: I think rather than writing rendered={!IF(relatedTo.opportunity__r.stageName!=null)} you should use rendered={!relatedTo.opportunity__r.stageName !=null}. there is not need to use if statement